MANOVA - Univariate Wilks' Lambda Test (R interpretation)
I am running a MANOVA model with 2 dependents and 2 continuous predictors.  (fyi - STATA calls this MANCOVA and requires dropping a "c." in front of each predictor to denote that each is continuously scaled during a manova run).  At any rate, R will directly accept continuous vars so there is no issue running MANCOVA in R using the manova command) - which is essentially MVNREG.
Using the UC-Irvine ML Repository Wine dataset, the model is:
model <- lm(cbind(alcohol, hue) ~ flavanoids + ash, 
             na.action=na.exclude, data=wine)
wine.manova=manova(model)

I am trying to understand the difference between the F approximations for Wilks' Lambda for the flavanoids predictor when using the two methods:
Method 1
library(car)
lh.out <- linearHypothesis(model, 
             hypothesis.matrix = c("flavanoids = 0"))
lh.out

for which results are:

Method 2
and the value of Wilks' based on the command
summary(wine.manova,'Wilks')

for which the output is:

Although the p-values are the same, I am trying to understand why the F values for Wilks' Lambda vary for the two tests of a zero coefficient for the flavanoids predictor based on all the response variables.  It works out that when there are more predictors or dependent variables, the difference is greater between these two calculations for Wilks' Lambda.
FYI - When benchmarking R against STATA, it's nearly impossible to obtain the table results listed under Method 2 above in STATA, while results from Method 1 are easily obtainable from STATA.
